# Table layout views

Tags: android, tablelayout

In my application i am showing one table layout.Please refer this image "http://www.freeimagehosting.net/5yhn3".This is my output. In that what i want is i need some 5 pixel space between value(14362) and that line,also i need the same in between line and Household(in column2).I tried something like textview(margin left and right) but if do that means that line also dislocating.

My table layout code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse" >
        <TextView           
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Income" >
        </TextView>
        <TextView           
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"          
            android:text="Expense" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text40"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Household:"
             >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />      


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text41"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text42"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trlinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Travel" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text43"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trlexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eduinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Education" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text45"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eduexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text46"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group4:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp4inctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group4" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text47"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group4:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp4exptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group4:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text48"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group5:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp5inctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group5" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text49"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group5:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp5exptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group5:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

          <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="40px">              
              <TextView       
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Total:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totincome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="total" >
    </TextView>  

    <TextView       
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Total:" 
       >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totexpense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="total:" >
    </TextView>    
 </TableRow>

               <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="40px">
 <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Balance:"  android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"  >
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/balance"
           android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="balance"  android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"  >
     </TextView>  
 </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Please help me..

My output should look like this

```
Household:   14326 | Household:  677
```

But i what have is:

```
Household:  14326|Household:  677
```

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity=center,  see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse" >
        <TextView           
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Income" >
        </TextView>
        <TextView           
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"          
            android:text="Expense" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text40"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"    //  <--------  Edit  This
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"    //  <--------  Edit  This
            android:text="Household:"
             >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />      


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text41"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"    //  <--------  Edit  This
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"    //  <--------  Edit  This
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text42"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trlinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Travel" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text43"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trlexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eduinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Education" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text45"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eduexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text46"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group4:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp4inctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group4" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text47"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group4:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp4exptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group4:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text48"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group5:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp5inctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group5" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text49"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group5:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp5exptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group5:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

          <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="40px">              
              <TextView       
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Total:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totincome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="total" >
    </TextView>  

    <TextView       
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Total:" 
       >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totexpense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="total:" >
    </TextView>    
 </TableRow>
               <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="40px">
 <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Balance:"  android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"  >
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/balance"
           android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="balance"  android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"  >
     </TextView>  
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: No @prakash, at my side I ckecked by putting larger Text in  <TextView android:id="@+id/houseinctot".. Then data is displayed in two lines. Data is not collapsed, You have edited some others properties also, then it can be happened.

Comment: K Chintan Raghwani ..What can i do to achieve this space problem..because i am wondering for this..

Comment: Just try one trick, put your <TextView ndroid:id="@+id/houseinctot".. Within a RelativeLayout and set this RelativeLayout's Gravity (also try layout_gravity) to CENTER.